# Mock Angular JS Controller Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, tdd

I am new to angular js.. just built an sample controller.. and now want to unit test it.. not sure how to write mock it in jasmine..

**TestApp.js**

```
var TestApp = angular.module('TestApp');  
TestApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test";
    });
})();
```

**TestApp_Spec.js**

```
var scope, ctrl;

//you need to inject dependencies first
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();        
}));

it('test value should be test', inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('TestCtrl', {
        scope: $scope
    });
    expect(scope.test).toBe("test");
}));
```

I am using stand alone version of jasmine and included angular.min.js, angular.mocks.js,TestApp.js and TestApp_Spec.js in the sepc_runner.html

Test results are not showing up..

Need help in writing the correct test cases..

Comment: What do you mean aren't showing up? You can't run them? The tests fail? Looking at your code you need to add beforeEach(module('TestApp')); above the other beforeEach

Comment: With my code, I was getting weird errors.. made code changes as suggested in the below answer, it worked fine. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some fixes in your code like you've not inserted module in your test suit so jasmine is not able to find the `controller`.

You have not passed second parameter which is an array as dependency in your module i.e `angular.module('TestApp',[]);`

[Here is the working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/FyDnCyRibOiL5fGVLcEB?p=preview)

**app.js**

```
(function(){
var TestApp = angular.module('TestApp',[]);  
TestApp.controller('TestCtrl',["$scope",function(scope) {
        alert(scope)
        scope.test = "test";
    }]);
})();
```

**Test Suit**

```
var scope, ctrl;
describe('MyApp', function() {
  beforeEach(module('TestApp'));
  //you need to inject dependencies first

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope) {
     scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
     $controller('TestCtrl', {
          '$scope': scope
      });       
  }));

  it('test value should be test',function(){
    expect(scope.test).toBe("test");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if my controller has another dependency..(function(){
var TestApp = angular.module('TestApp',['AnotherApp']);  
TestApp.controller('TestCtrl',["$scope",function(scope) {
        alert(scope)
        scope.test = "test";
    }]);
})();